# is that possible to load a local file from remote swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, security, apache-flex, cross-domain-policy

Remote swf can not access a local file. Here is the error details :

> SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file http://
>   www.mydomain.com/ClipboardTest.swf cannot access local resource
>   file:///C:\Temp\clip_image001.jpg. Only local-with-filesystem and
>   trusted local SWF files may access local resources.

I have tried Security.allowDomain("*"); and cross-domain-policy-file. is there any solution?

Comment: compile with `-use-network=false`

Comment: -use-network=false doesn'work :/

Comment: not possible for good reason.

Comment: How are you trying to load your local `.jpg` file?  As others have said, direct file access is expressly prohibited for security reasons, but you might be able to accomplish your goal using `FileReference`.

Comment: I am using `Loader`. I have no another choice to get the file from local file system. Because I need to copy an email from outlook to TextArea with the attached pictures and during the proces the pictures are copied in temp folder. I have to get the pictures from temp folder. I have tried `FileReference`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's impossible at least according to what Adobe said. Look here for more details : [Remote sandboxes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e3f.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7c55)

For info, a very good tutorial speaking about flash security : [Security Domains, Application Domains, and More in ActionScript 3.0](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/contentdomains/)

Comment: I read the adobe documents and the document from senocular, but I need a solution.

Comment: I understand, but if Adobe said : "Remote SWF files cannot load any local files or resources." unfortunately we can not do anything, it is their technology ;)

Comment: I understad. Thank you for the reply ;)

Comment: May be if you explain why do you need this, may we can help you to find another solution or proposal.

Comment: I need to copy an email from outlook to TextArea with the attached pictures and during the process the pictures are copied in temp folder. I have to get the pictures from temp folder.

Comment: How do you copy that email from outlook ? And outlook is the site outlook.com or MS email client (the app) ? Why your swf (ClipboardTest.swf) is not local ? could you explain more ? more you give us details more we have ability to help you.

Comment: That (ClipboardTest.swf) is a email module and works on the server. An email can be copied (copy/paste) from outlook-client or from a web site to email module (as html with pictures and links). When I copy an email from outlook, the attached pictures are copied in windows/temp folder and then I call the pictures via `AS3 Loader` from temp to display in email module, but Flash Player says that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with any local files on a computer when the 'Network Only' is enabled. This is an important security feature of flash.

Although, I am pretty sure there's a way to save local files for game saves (like variables and stuff) on flash, even when it uses Network Only. If this is the type of thing you need, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595431/how-to-i-make-my-flash-as3-game-save-progress).

Personally I've never tried it out so I don't know how capable it is. Hope it helps though.